# Internal structures, factorizations and Baer sum

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Given a category $C$ and an object $x : C_0$, there is a correspondence between the internal monoid structures on $x$ and the factorizations of the contravariant hom functor of type

[image: controvariant hom functor on sets factoring through forgetful functor from monoids to sets]

My question is if there are criteria for such factorizations in a more general settings: assuming that $C$ is endowed with a monoidal structure and that the Hom functor is replaced with a "nice" functor (and Mon replaced with a generic algebraic theory, such as Ab).

Particularly, my interest is directed torward a categorical understanding of why Yoneda extension sets have an abelian group structure defined in such a way.

I realize that this question is vague, it reflects my lack of understanding, but any input is appreciated.

---

**Update**

I've had some time to think about this question. The result I want to understand is the following:

**Proposition** If $F \colon \text{Mod}_A \to \text{Set}$ is a functor that preserves finite products then it factors through the forgetful functor $U \colon \text{Ab} \to \text{Set}$.

The first step in the proof of this result is showing that the isomorphisms
$$F(x \oplus y) \cong F(x) \times F(y)$$
(and similarly for unit) can be chosen so that they form a natural isomorphism, ie. a monoidal functor.

The best result I've found so far on nlab is [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor#properties).
This is the same as the argument given in the [link by jgon](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2724962/90543), ie. using diagonal to show that it preserves products (in the first variable, which is covariant) and the codiagonal to show that it preserves coproducts (in the second one, which is contravariant).

Monoids are weak for the result that we wish for, but we cannot hope to generalize to any kind of algebraic structure for free.
I was thinking that maybe we can show that

- if the theorem holds ($C$ has finite products and there are factorizations through an algebraic category) then $C$ has at least the same structure of such algebraic category,
- this is enough for the theorem to hold.

Hope that this makes the question more concrete.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2724962/90543) might be helpful for the Baer extension sets part of this question.

Comment: This form of internalisation works well for any kind of algebraic structure defined by limits – for example, monoids, groups, rings, categories, etc. However, this doesn't interact well with the monoidal structure of $\mathcal{C}$ (if it has one).

Comment: I don't recommend that you use Baer sum to try to understand conceptually why Ext has a group structure. $\text{Ext}^1(A, B)$ has a group structure because it's a hom $\text{Hom}(A, B[1]])$ in the derived category, and the derived category is additive so its hom functor takes values in abelian groups. This explains much more about Ext, such as why there's a composition map $\text{Ext}^n(A, B) \otimes \text{Ext}^m(B, C) \to \text{Ext}^{n+m}(A, C)$; it's just composition in the derived category.

Comment: I like the analogy given by Roland! I wrote monoidal structure, but I have in mind the cartesian one. The result I want to see in categorical terms is the following: if a functor $F \colon \text{Mod}_A \to \text{Set}$ preserves finite products, then it factors through $\text{Ab}$. I don't know much about monoidal structures and such, but I was hoping the answer was in this direction. [This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12182) gave me the impression that Ext can be useful as it is; yet I see that homology point of view yields a good understanding. Thank you all.