# Neutral element in $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ a ringed space and $ \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G} \in (\mathcal{O}_X\mathcal{-Mod})$ two arbitrary $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. The canonical bifunctors

$$\operatorname{Ext}^i(-,-): (\mathcal{O}_X\mathcal{-Mod})^{op} \times \mathcal{O}_X\mathcal{-Mod} \to \operatorname{Ab}$$

are derived functors of the bifunctor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(-,-): (\mathcal{O}_X\mathcal{-Mod})^{op} \times \mathcal{O}_X\mathcal{-Mod} \to \operatorname{Ab}$.

On can show that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})= \operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ has a interpretation as set of classes of extensions $0 \to \mathcal{F} \to ? \to \mathcal{G} \to 0$. But it is moreover claimed that $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ has structure of abelian groups.

How the group operation in is defined and what is neutral element in $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$? As a natural guess for the neutral element can be considered the splitting extension $0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F} \oplus \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0$ since this extension always exist und therefore it can be considered as a kind of 'canonical' choice. That's of course only a conjecture. I'm seeking for a formal argument why this choice indeed gives the neural element of $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Baer sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#The_Baer_sum_of_extensions) operation?

Comment: I have to take a closer look at it, but seems to behave well with glueing. Here I think we can use the strategy you proposed in my external powers question and claim that $0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F} \oplus \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0$? Then we need it only to check locally and this reduces it to modules over a ring problem.

Comment: Sure, this can also be defined completely categorically, see the following duplicate target. Roland's answer there is completely general and will work in any abelian category.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Baer Sum notation requires clearence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703387/baer-sum-notation-requires-clearence)

Comment: If we use now only the categorical definition of Bear sum from the linked question, how we can conclude that the split extension $0 \to A \xrightarrow{j_A} A \oplus B \xrightarrow{p_B} B \to 0$ is the neutral element? 

For convenience we alter my notation to that from the linked question. That is we have to show for arbitrary extension $0 \to A  \xrightarrow{f} E \xrightarrow{g} B \to 0$ and the split extension $0 \to A \xrightarrow{j_A} A \oplus B \xrightarrow{p_B} B \to 0$ the first

Comment: extension $0 \to A  \xrightarrow{f} E \xrightarrow{g} B \to 0$ is equivalent to the image of the extension class $0 \to A \oplus A \xrightarrow{f \oplus j_A} E \oplus A \oplus B \xrightarrow{ g \oplus p_B} B \to 0 \in \operatorname{Ext}(A \oplus A, B \oplus B)$ by the composition $\operatorname{Ext}(A \oplus A, B \oplus B) \xrightarrow{\Delta_A^*} \operatorname{Ext}(A, B \oplus B) \xrightarrow{\nabla_B^*} \operatorname{Ext}(A , B) $. How can I show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{E,E'}$ be two extensions of $\mathcal{G}$ by $\mathcal{F}$ :
$$0\to \mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{f}\mathcal{E}\xrightarrow{g}\mathcal{G}\to 0$$
$$0\to \mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{f'}\mathcal{E'}\xrightarrow{g'}\mathcal{G'}\to 0$$

Consider the maps $i:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{E\oplus E'}$ given on a section $s$ by $i(s)=(f(s),-f'(s))$, and the map $p:\mathcal{E\oplus E'}\to\mathcal{G}$ given by $p(s,s')=g(s)-g'(s')$. The Baer sum of $\mathcal{E,E'}$ is then given by $\ker p/\operatorname{im} i$.

Now assume $\mathcal{E'}$ is the trivial extension :
$$0\to\mathcal{F}\xrightarrow{j}\mathcal{F\oplus G}\xrightarrow{q}\mathcal{G}\to 0$$

Then $\ker p$ is the subsheaf of $\mathcal{E\oplus F\oplus G}$ of sections $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ such that $g(s_1)-q(s_2,s_3)=0$ or equivalently $g(s_1)=s_3$.
Define a map $u:\ker p\to \mathcal{E}$ such that $(s_1,s_2,s_3)\mapsto s_1+f(s_2)$. We have $u\circ i(s)=u(f(s),-s,0)=f(s)-f(s)=0$ so the map $u$ factors as a map $\ker p/\operatorname{im}i$.

Check that $u$ is a morphism of extensions. As such, it is automatically an isomorphism. But for sake of completeness, we can write its inverse : it is given by $v:\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{E\oplus F\oplus G}/\operatorname{im}i$ given by $v(s)=(s,0,g(s))$. Check that $p\circ v=0$ so that $v$ factor through $\ker p/\operatorname{im}i$.

We trivially have $u\circ v=\operatorname{id}$. We also have $v\circ u(s_1,s_2,s_3)=v(s_1+f(s_2))=(s_1+f(s_2),0,g(s_1+f(s_2)))$. Now $g(s_1+f(s_2))=g(s_1)$ since $g\circ f=0$ and $g(s_1)=s_3$ since $(s_1,s_2,s_3)\in\ker p$. Hence $v\circ u(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(s_1+f(s_2),0,s_3)=(s_1,s_2,s_3)+(f(s_2),-f(s_2),0)$. But $(f(s_2),-f(s_2),0)=i(s_2,s_3)=0$ in $\ker p/\operatorname{im} i$. It follows that $v\circ u=\operatorname{id}$ as expected.

Comment: Hi Roland, when you say a 'section $s$' you are talking about arbitrary $s \in \mathcal{F}(U), U \subset X$ open, since all your arguments seem to be compatible with restriction maps $\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(V)$ for $V \subset U \subset X$? A nitpick: do you how the proof of the same claim can be generalized to arbitrary Abelian categories? The point is that you used several times that you can take a concrete section $s$ (or concrete ring element $r \in R$) but arguments like this in arbitrary Abelian category may not work.

Comment: One possibility is to use Freyd's embedding thereom to embed the abelian category in a $R$-Mod caegory. theoretically it works always but it not so 'sleek'. Do you know a pure 'abstract nonsense' argument for this claim?

Comment: I used elements as a way to easily define a morphism but all of these can easily be skipped. For example, the definition of $i$ can easily be written without element as "by universality of the biproduct, the maps $f,-f'$ define a map $i:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{E\oplus E'}$". You can check that every map as wrote can also be written that way. To check that $u$ is a morphism of extensions can be checked using the commutative square which come from the definitions of $i$ and $p$. The fact that $u$ is an isomorphism follows from the five lemma if one wants to skip the use of $v$.

Comment: So the same proof holds in any abelian category without the use of elements, it is just more diagrams. You can also use "elements in an arbitrary category" if you are familiar with this concept.

Comment: the only part which still confuses me is how we see $u \circ i=0$ only categorically? As you said $i$ can be caracterized by universality of the biproduct and therefore the notation $i = (f, -f')= (f,-j)$ make sense. Also if we use again the universality of $\mathcal{E\oplus F\oplus G}$ then $u$ can defined by notation $id_{E} +f +0$ meaning that $u$ is the unique morphism induced by $id_E: \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}, f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ and the zero morphism  $0: \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: I understand the '+' notation in $u=id_{E} +f +0$ in this abstract setting only as it just *symbolically* reminds that $u$ is formed by universality of coproduct. Therefore in the composition $u \circ i= (id_E + f+0) \circ (f,-j):\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ seemingly we cannot use this 'calculus' with '+' to argue $(id_E + f+0) \circ (f,-j)= f +(-f \circ j)= f-f=0$ since $u \circ i$ hasn't stucture $A \oplus B \to C$. How can I prove formally correct that $u \circ i=0$ with diagrams?

Comment: @user7391733 It can be shown that in any abelian category, matrix calculus holds. So for example the map $i:\mathcal{F\to E\oplus F\oplus G}$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}f\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Similarily $u:\mathcal{E\oplus F\oplus G\to E}$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}1&f&0\end{pmatrix}$. So $u\circ i=0$.

Comment: I just want to add that you should not focus too much on what is possible in an abstract category and what require elements. In this particular example, every map is explicit and constructed using universal properties. The use of elements is just to simplify the notations, but you can see them as generalized elements (ie map from $X$ and use Yoneda to conclude the equalities...). The difficulty in abstract categories arise in fact when you have non explicit maps and want to do some diagram chase (like snake lemma, five lemma...)